# When I set the value of local to be greater than 1, why did pyspark resort the error

Tags: python, pyspark

When I set the value of `local` to 1, the operation is normal, but when set to 2, the error message is reported as follows

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
# Changing 1 to 2 will give you an error
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "sort")


class MySort:
    def __init__(self, tup):
        self.tup = tup

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.tup[0] > other.tup[0]:
            return True
        elif self.tup[0] == other.tup[0]:
            if self.tup[1] >= other.tup[1]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False


r1 = sc.parallelize([(1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 1), (1, 3)])
r2 = r1.sortBy(MySort)
print(r2.collect())
```

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\spark2.3.1\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 230, in main
  File "E:\spark2.3.1\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 225, in process
  File "E:\spark2.3.1\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 376, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "E:\spark2.3.1\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 555, in dumps
    return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup MySort on __main__ failed
```

Comment: can you add error messega?

Comment: sorry,I forgot it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add params to spark-submit with file with your class:

`--py-files your_file.py`

because spark needs to pass this class to another worker.

Comment: You need to separate your class to new file.

Comment: this is my submit script `./bin/spark-submit --py-files /root/python_code/spark/p8.py /root/python_code/spark/p8.py`

Comment: ./bin/spark-submit --py-files /root/python_code/spark/file_with_your_class.py /root/python_code/spark/main_only_with_spark_job.py

Answer (score 0):

Its really interesting attribute of spark i did not know it before. I think when you use single core, classes are not pickled(pickle is needed to use class in other places). But you can still use functions (i assume you sorted values by first two values):

```
key_func = lambda tup : tup[:2]

r1 = sc.parallelize([(1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 1), (1, 3)])
r2 = r1.sortBy(key_func)
print(r2.collect())
```

Comment: I agree with you about the reasons for the problem,but the problem that this approach solves is limited, and I want a general solution.

Comment: You can add example limitation.

Comment: The first value is ascending and the second value is descending

Comment: You can multiply with -1. `lambda tup: (-1*tup[0], tup[1])`

Comment: `r=sc.parallelize([1,3,5,6,7])`,The sort rule is to see who is closer to 2,If the distance is the same, put the one greater than 2 in front,the result I want is[3,1,5,6,7]

Comment: `lambda x: (abs(2-x), -1*x)`

Comment: It seems that you are right,but I have another question,both list and MySort extend  object,Why can list be serialized?

Comment: I dont know. I am just just guessing that it can be related to java class and python class difference.